# Novelette about contact with intergalactic inhabitants after interstellar jump failure

Tags: story-identification, first-contact, novella

I read a novelette a long time ago, but I can't remember its name or author, in which an Earth interstellar ship has a problem during a jump from one star to another and ends up returning from the jump between the Milky Way and the Andromeda Galaxy. There they find gigantic beings that inhabit this intergalactic space, and with which they can communicate.

Does it ring any bells?

Thanks in advance.
Nelson

Comment: How long is a long time ago, approximately? What were the gigantic beings like?

Comment: I don't remember how long ago, but I have the impression that the writing style, afair, points to the 1950s.

Comment: I might, even, have re-read it in the last 4 years in one of the SF Megapacks published by Wildside Press LLC. Besides being gigantic, the communication is achieved via infrared or some other kind of radiation. The mental image that I have about them is octopus alike, but this may be a false lead.

Comment: Are the giant space beings friendly, hostile, or indifferent?

Comment: In the beginning they seem to be indifferent. After the humans can communicate, they are friendly.

Comment: Yes, they are old, although there is an "young" one who helps in the communications, afair.

Answer (score 2):

This somewhat reminds me of [Port Eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_Realities_(Cherryh)#Port_Eternity) by C J Cherrryh, which features a ship trapped in an alternate dimension after a hyperspace jump goes awry, and a subsequent meeting with a large variety of aliens also trapped there.

I'm not sure it's the same story though because

> it turns out to be a one way trip in that case.

Comment: Thanks, but that one isn't it. And, since I haven't read it, I'll add it to my backlog.